# Regex expression not extracting tokens

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use python's built in re module to extract tokens from an input, however it isn't producing the intended result.

```
import re


def main():
    rules = {
        'number' : r"(?P<int>\d+)",
        'Test' : r"(^((P=int)\s?)*$)"
    }

    lex = ''
    for rule in rules:
        lex += rules[rule]
    p = re.compile(lex)
    x = p.match("12 34 56 + - * / %")
    if x:
        print(x)
    elif type(x) == list:
        print('returned empty list')
    else:
        print("No matches")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the intended result of this would be `['12', '34', '56']`, but it instead outputs `no matches`

Comment: What are `x` and `type(x)` actually?

Comment: earlier ``match`` was returning an empty list, so i had that there for debugging purposes

Comment: Sure, but try printing `x` and `type(x)` before the `if` statements and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to use [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) instead of [`match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match).